# How can I handle a date picker with a month and a year that are kept in the same html tag using Selenium Webriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, logic

I want to create a method that accepts a String variable in the following format ' **1 April 2018**'. This string would be then split and the date 'ingredients' would be used to select the date in the picker [See the picker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlE1X.png). I have already covered picking the days and clicking the arrows changing the 'month-year' pair. I also know how to reach the year inserted by the user, but I am unsure how to select the correct month when the year is reached. Below is the code I came up with so far.

```
public void pickTheDate() {

    String date = "10 April 2018";
    String[] dateElements = date.split(" ");
    WebElement nextMonth = driver.findElement(By.xpath("somexpath"));
    WebElement previousMonth = driver.findElement(By.xpath("somexpath1"));

    String dayFromUserInput = dateElements[0];
    String monthFromUserInput = dateElements[1];
    String yearFromUserInput = dateElements[2];

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    WebElement datePickerHeader= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("somexpath")));
    String textFromDatePickerHeader = datePickerHeader.getText();
```

Let's pretend that the date in the date picker header is 'October 2017'

```
    String[] dateElementsFromDatePickerHeader = textFromDatePickerHeader.split(" ");
    int yearDiff = Integer.parseInt(yearFromUserInput) - Integer.parseInt(dateElementsFromDatePickerHeader[1]);

    if (yearDiff != 0) {
        //moving to next year
        if (yearDiff > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < yearDiff; i++) {
                nextMonth.click();
            }
```

At this point I know the month I reach is 'January 2018'

```
        }
        //moving to previous year
        else if (yearDiff < 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (yearDiff * (-1)); i++) {
                previousMonth.click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I would be searching for a date within 2016 I know that the first encountered month would be 'December 2016'.
Please advise how I can incorporate the proper logic for navigation to the month inserted by the user. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its depend on your Date picker behavior. For reference I following structure of Date Picker :

[image]

If  click on "October 2017" Header then it opens months for selection as below image :

[image]

And again click On "2017" header then opens Years for selection

[image]

So here the automation testcases will be

1. Get the date as 25 October 2017
2. Split the date in 3 chunks
3. Click on the header and navigate till it show the years list to select
4. Navigate the calendar to received year i.e. **2017**
5. Then navigate and select the month as received i.e. **October**
6. And finally Select the Date i.e. **25**

Find the sample code here :

```
public void enterFromDate(String fromDate) throws InterruptedException
{
     // Split the data and store it in string array
     String[]  data = fromDate.split(" ");

     // click datepicker icon
     fromDateCalenderIcon.click();
     // Click date picker header, It moves to month list
     calenderHeader.click();
     // Again click date picker header, It now moves to Year listing
     calenderHeader.click();


     mainloop: while(true)
     {
         //Iterate all year
         for(int i=0;i<datePickerData.size();i++)
         {
             // check weather year available in list if yes then select it 
             if(datePickerData.get(i).getText().trim().contains(data[2]))
             {

                 datePickerData.get(i).click();     
                 break mainloop;                     
             }
         }
          // else click back arrow 
         datePickerLeftArrow.click();
     }

     // Iterate month list
     for(WebElement e: datePickerData)
     {
         // If months available then click on it 
         if(e.getText().equals(data[1]))
         {
             e.click();
             break;
         }
     }

     // Iterate Date and select as required 
     for(WebElement e: datePickerData)
     {
         if((e.getText().equals(data[0]) && (e.findElement(By.tagName("span"))).getAttribute("class").equals("ng-binding")))
         {
             e.click();
             break;
         }
     }
}
```